# XPath not finding any results

Tags: python, xpath, python-requests, lxml

**Using Python 3.4, lxml, and requests to scrape google trends.**

In this example, I'm trying to retrieve the text "Johnny Depp" located between these span tags. I'm new to the lxml module and XPath syntax but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong at this point.

Thank you in advance.

**HTML:**

```
<span class="hottrends-single-trend-title ellipsis-maker-inner">Johnny Depp</span>
```

**Code:**

```
from lxml import html
import requests

page = requests.get('https://trends.google.com/trends/hottrends')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

#This will create a list of trends:
trends = tree.xpath('//span[@class="hottrends-single-trend-title ellipsis-maker-inner"]/text()')

print('Trends: ', trends)
```

**Results:**
[image]

Comment: `'hottrends-single-trend-title' in page.text` returns False. Are you sure the tag is on the page? Note that requests module doesn't support dynamic content like javascript or HTML5.

Comment: I just tried to load your url with disabled javascript, and it shows a blank page. Try to use this url instead: https://trends.google.com/trends/hottrends/atom/feed?pn=p1 (got from the three-dot menu).

Comment: @Meloman, thank you, that makes sense as the feed is probably populated by JS. When I viewed the source of this atom feed I see that all of the XML in one tag. Could you point me in the right direction for parsing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the corresponding RSS URL you can use `lxml`'s XML parser or even `xml.etree` from the standard library since the XML structure is much simpler than the HTML counterpart. Given the RSS XML, you can just iterate through `item` elements and print the `title`, for example (though the top result is no longer 'Johnny Depp' now :)) :

```
>>> from lxml import etree as ET
>>> import requests
>>> page = requests.get('https://trends.google.com/trends/hottrends/atom/feed?pn=p1')
>>> root = ET.fromstring(page.content)
>>> for trend in root.xpath('//item'):
...     print trend.find('title').text
... 
spinner
Old Navy Flip Flop Sale
You Get Me
Johnny Depp
NHL Draft
GLOW
Despicable Me 3
Blake Griffin
Robert Del Naja
DJ Khaled Grateful
Bella Thorne
Tubelight
interstellar
Camila Cabello
Mexico vs Russia
Frank Mason
Bam Adebayo
TJ Leaf
the house
Dwyane Wade
```